# django url regex - how to interprete this?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

Noticed this urls.py definition in an open source django app.

```
r'^(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w]+)/$
```

How do I interprete the `(?!signout|signup|signin)` component?

I understand the `P<username>` but I am not sure what `(?!signout|signup|signin)` is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a NOT operator. It matches if the text is not `signout`, `signup`, or `signin`.

See Python's [re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> (?!...)
>
> Matches if `...` doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s not followed by `'Asimov'`.